# Startup.cs not needed on DEV machine but needed for deployment

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin

I am developing an ASP.NET Web API v2 application. My application works fine from my DEV machine but when I go to deploy it to my server it gives the following errors.

```
The following errors occurred while attempting to load the app.
- No assembly found containing an OwinStartupAttribute.
- No assembly found containing a Startup or [AssemblyName].Startup class.
To disable OWIN startup discovery, add the appSetting owin:AutomaticAppStartup with a value of "false" in your web.config.
To specify the OWIN startup Assembly, Class, or Method, add the appSetting owin:AppStartup with the fully qualified startup class or configuration method name in your web.config.
```

After searching Google, SO, and other sites I found adding a default Startup.cs class to my project fixed the issue. The problem is I don't know how.

[image]

1. What did adding Startup.cs do?
2. Why would my app compile and run on my development machine without Startup.cs?
3. This seems to involve `OWIN` but I was not even aware I was making use of any `OWIN` features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely due to the way OWIN searches for its entry point (`Startup` class).  In your dev environment you probably have a DLL in the project folder that has an OWIN Startup class.  That dll is not being deployed as part of the deployment step and therefore doesn't exist in your deployed location.

Another posibility, along the same lines, is you're using .config transformations and you have defined a Startup class in your DEV config but not in your deployed config.

```
<appSettings>  
  <add key="owin:appStartup" value="StartupDemo.ProductionStartup" />
</appSettings>
```

[OWIN Startup Class Detection](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection) might be informative.

MVC5 uses OWIN pipeline by default so it's "under the hood". Perhaps you migrated from a previous MVC site and that's why the Startup class was missing?

Cheers!

Comment: When I add Startup.cs to the project the references to Microsoft.Owin cannot seem to be resolved. I see the Owin.dll in my project references but Startup.cs can't seem to locate it.

Comment: Are there any negatives to not including the Startup.cs and avoiding the Owin Startup check by using this value in the web.config? `<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />`

Comment: If you're not using any Owin components and don't need to add to the Owin pipeline then I don't think there is any issue with that.